# Top X% in profile

Tags: discussion, profile-page

What does Top X% this (week, quarter) in my profile mean?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The number tells you where you stand reputation-wise.

If you are in the top 15%, for example, 85% of users have less reputation than you; 15% have the same amount or more.

[image]

Comment: You're going to use that toy a lot now, aren't you?

Comment: @squillman ooh boy, yes! I already have a light-beige-coloured "canvas.png" for quick uploading. :)

Comment: You're not afraid of [image rot](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81441/stackexchange-supercollider-freehand-circle-editor/81668#81668)?

Comment: @Arjan: That's been fixed now.

Comment: Your art needs much to be desired. :) P.S. Since when did @JonSkeet have 0 rep...?