# my reputation? what does it mean top 15%?

Tags: discussion, reputation, reputation-leagues

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Top X% in profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81589/top-x-in-profile)

244
reputation
top 15% this week

what does it mean top 15%?

Comment: It means you're going to need to work much harder to catch up with Jon Skeet.

Comment: Not much.  I think counting users with 1 rep shouldn't be counted in the stats.

Comment: @Will are ALL users counted? I thought <200 rep users were not tracked in the leagues?

Comment: @giddy leagues are one thing, your percentage as reported on your profile is another.  Seems like people with 100 rep are still in the top 10%, which suggests to me they're counting all users in that.

Comment: @Will I see.thanks. I happen to be top 2% this week but it still makes me happy tho =D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meaning you get more rep faster than 85% of the other users

Answer (score 4):

It means the amount of reputation you got this week puts you in the Top 15% of all users.

If you click on it, it will take you to the [stackexchange.com reputation league page](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow), which shows leagues weekly, monthly, quarterly and yearly.

If you also navigate to the Users page on stackoverflow you will see something similar. (Your daily and weekly rep gain is also displayed on the drop down view when you hover on the down pointer on your username on the top.)

Answer (score 4):

The amount of reputation you've gained *in this week* puts you within the top 15% of reputation gained as compared to other users *for this week*.  If I'm not mistaken it's also a rolling percentage.  If you gain even more today you might be in the top 12% this week tomorrow, or in the top 17% if you don't gain any/gain as much.